# Google maps API passing information between functions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm having difficulty assigning a marker to my map when placed in a function outside of where the map is initialised.

I have a fixed maker that is placed when the map is loaded which works fine.  I also want a marker to be placed on the location of the user visiting the page.  I have placed the second part in a separate function called getUserLocation().

I have tried calling the getMap() function within the getUserLocation() function but it’s not working.  I assume that what I’m after is possible? Example below.

```
// Get user location
function getUserLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            // Users location
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            console.log(pos);

            var userLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: pos });

            getMap();

        }, function() {             
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    }
}

// Initialise Google Maps
function getMap() {

    var mapOptions = {
        center: {lat: 50.7367030, lng: -3.5171710}, 
        zoom: 13
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    // Home marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: {lat: 50.7367030, lng: -3.5171710}
    });
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `getUserLocation`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered a similar question about markers just yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43643419/4465920).

I just edited it to your needs.

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  addmarker('-22.3157017', '-49.0660877');
});
$('#button2').click(function() {
  addmarker('-23.5936152', '-46.5856465');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button" style="width:80px;height:30px;cursor:pointer;">
  Click
</button>
<button id="button2" style="width:80px;height:30px;cursor:pointer;">
  Click2
</button>
<div id="map" style="width:555px;height:500px"></div>
<script>
  function getMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.7367030, -3.5171710),
      zoom: 13
    });

    addmarker(50.7367030, -3.5171710);
  }

  function addmarker(lat, lon) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
      map: map
    });

    map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
  }

  function getUserLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        //call function sending coordinates
        addmarker(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    }
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDL5dMHBCV7crlostybmkuGBAXjOP3yawQ&callback=getMap"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's exactly what i was after!

Answer (score 0):

Getmap initializes a new instance of the map, and it can be called just once. To change the marker's position, you must use another method.

```
function getUserLocation() {

if (navigator.geolocation) {

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

        // Users location
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        console.log(pos);

        var userLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map, position: pos });

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.lat, pos.lng);
        userlocationmarker.setPosition(myLatlng);

    }, function() {             
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  });
}
```

}

This new method (setPosition) just sets the marker's position to a new one (in this case, your user's position)