# Google Maps: Buttons doesn't work to show marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

(I'm very noob with this. I'm learning on my own, I know my code is messy.)

I am working with Google Maps API, and I want the user to click a button (either Restaurant 1 or Restaurant 2) and then have the map pan to the location of that restaurant, using a marker and a InfoWindow above. Simple, right?

Here's my HTML code so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>W3.CSS Template</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fuente1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fuente2.css">
<style>
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif}
</style>
<body class="w3-light-grey">

<!-- Page Container -->
<div class="w3-content w3-margin-top" style="max-width:1400px;">

  <!-- The Grid -->
  <div class="w3-row-padding">
  
    <!-- Left Column -->
<div class="w3-third">
    
      <div class="w3-white w3-text-grey w3-card-4">
        <div class="w3-container">
          <img><br>Choose a restaurant<p><br>
<button id="button" style="width:110px;height:30px;cursor:pointer;">Restaurant 1</button>
<button id="button2" style="width:110px;height:30px;cursor:pointer;">Restaurant 2</button>

            <!-- End Left Column -->    </p>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>

    <!-- Right Column -->
    <div class="w3-twothird">
    
      <div class="w3-container w3-card w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
<h2 class="w3-text-grey w3-padding-16"><i class="fa fa-suitcase fa-fw w3-margin-right w3-xxlarge w3-text-blue"></i>
MAP
</h2><div class="w3-container">
<html>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width:555px;height:500px"></div>
<script>
  function myMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.825948, -116.599869),
      zoom: 16
    });
  }

  function addmarker(lat, lon) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
      map: map
    });
    
    map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon));
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQ3QnkneaUIsXaJHZtYwqdWxX9KCMj4CA&callback=myMap">"></script>
</body>
</html>
       <br><br>

        </div>
      </div>
<!-- End Right Column -->
    </div>
    
  <!-- End Grid -->
  </div>
  
  <!-- End Page Container -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have everything set up. The only thing that doesn't work are the buttons.

I have the following Javascript but I have no idea whatsoever on how to implement it in my HTML.

```
    $('#button').click(function() {
  addmarker('-22.3157017', '-49.0660877');
});
$('#button2').click(function() {
  addmarker('-23.5936152', '-46.5856465');
});
```

I'll be happy to hear any lectures for this affair and any help will be greatly appreciated.

For reference, I want it to work pretty much like this one. [Place marker on google maps api with html button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642322/place-marker-on-google-maps-api-with-html-button/43643419)

Comment: First of all you need to fix your markup

Answer (score 0):

I did not use your markup - I've created my own.

Upon checking your javascript, everything seems well, except of these two things: **missing [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library** and **the code placement of your button event handlers**.

It seems you are trying to add **[Google Maps Javascript API Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)** to these locations "-22.3157017,-49.0660877" and "-23.5936152,-46.5856465" by pressing their corresponding triggers (buttons). I would suggest doing a **[Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)** before adding the markers once an event has been fired.

> The term geocoding generally refers to translating a human-readable
>   address into a location on a map. The process of doing the converse,
>   translating a location on the map into a human-readable address, is
>   known as reverse geocoding.

You should also add **jQuery** as an external library to make their events such as ".click()" to work. You can download it **[here](https://jquery.com/download/)**.

For the buttons, you should add these lines $('#button1').click(function()); and $('#button1').click(function()); inside your myMap() function.

It should look something like this:

```
  function myMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 31.825948, lng: -116.599869};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });
    $('#button1').click(function(){
      var coord = { lat: parseFloat('-22.3157017'), lng: parseFloat('-49.0660877') };
      addMarker( coord, map );
    });
     $('#button2').click(function(){
      var coord = { lat: parseFloat('-23.5936152'), lng: parseFloat('-46.5856465') };
      addMarker( coord, map );
    });        
  }
```

On your addMarker function, add two arguments that accepts the coordinates, and the map object.

```
function addMarker(params, map) {);
```

Inside that function, create a variable **geocoder** and the value is a new instance of google.maps.Geocoder().

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

With that, you can now use **geocode method**. Geocode method accepts two arguments: location and callback. In the **location** parameter, you need to supply the coordinates you acquired from the addMarker() function.

```
geocoder.geocode({'location' : params}, function( results, status ) {});
```

The **callback** is the part where most of our logic will be implemented. The callback accepts two arguments: results, and status. The **results** argument returns an array of results if the **status** is **OK**. If so, we will now iterate through each array element and then create a new **Google Maps Javascript API Markers**. On the markers, we'll just supply the coordinates and maps object for its position and map property.

```
if (status === 'OK') {         
  var result = results.map( function( value, index ){
   map.setCenter(params);                                               
   var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
       position : params,
       map : map,
    });                 
  });   
 } else {
   alert('Geo not successful: ' + status);
 }
```

This line 'map.setCenter(params);' sets the position displayed by the map.

Whole code below:

```
<button id="button1">Restaurant 1</button>
<button id="button2">Restaurant 2</button>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&callback=myMap">
    </script>

  function myMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: 31.825948, lng: -116.599869};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });
    $('#button1').click(function(){
      var coord = { lat: parseFloat('-22.3157017'), lng: parseFloat('-49.0660877') };
      addMarker( coord, map );
    });
     $('#button2').click(function(){
      var coord = { lat: parseFloat('-23.5936152'), lng: parseFloat('-46.5856465') };
      addMarker( coord, map );
    });       
  }
  function addMarker(params, map) {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({'location' : params}, function( results, status ) {
        if (status === 'OK') {         
            var result = results.map( function( value, index ){
            map.setCenter(params);                                               
            var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position : params,
              map : map,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            });                 
            });   
          } else {
            alert('Geo not successful: ' + status);
          }

      });

 }
```

Hope it could help and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this before on stackoverflow for how to show icons and infowindow and just updated my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/MKSnD/) to use https instead. Following are very simple steps you need to take care of.

1. When you click on that fiddle you will see all HTML, JS and CSS I have used to show icons on map, list of people on car and interactivity to click on them to centre on map.
2. Using gmap3 library I have inlcuded google map on page
3. Using List elements I have coded location of items at `<li data-gb="car" data-mapid="sc102" data-isactive="0" data-lat="53.538566" data-long="-0.327017199999951">Second Car</li>` in data attributes for each item. It can be restuarants, parks etc

Important bits in code are in Javascript and these are
Events and Addmarker actions as well as logic to click on list items.

```
{ action: 'addMarkers',
marker:{
values:ulmarkerspeople,
options:{
    draggable: false,
    icon:'http://webricate.com/stackoverflow/mapicons/male-2.png'
},
events:{
  mouseover: function(marker, event, context){
    var listelement = jQuery("li[data-mapid='"+context.data.id+"']");
    jQuery(listelement).attr('style','background-color:#ccc');
    jQuery(listelement).attr('data-isactive','1');
    var map = $(this).gmap3("get"),
      infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}});
    if (infowindow){
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      infowindow.setContent(context.data.ht);
      jQuery("#customPopup").html(context.data.ht);
        jQuery("#customPopup").show(500);
    } else {
      $(this).gmap3({
        infowindow:{
          anchor:marker, 
          options:{content: context.data.ht}

        }
      });
        jQuery("#customPopup").html(context.data.ht);
        jQuery("#customPopup").show(500);
    }
  },
  mouseout: function(marker,event,context){
    var listelement = jQuery("li[data-mapid='"+context.data.id+"']");
    jQuery(listelement).attr('style','background-color:#fff');
    jQuery(listelement).attr('data-isactive','0');
    var infowindow = $(this).gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}});
    if (infowindow){
      infowindow.close();

      jQuery("#customPopup").hide(500);
      jQuery("#customPopup").html("");
    }
   }
  }
 } 
}
```

Please read through Javascript comments on fiddle and you will get the gist of it.